# scrollbar Qt, can't scroll

Tags: c++, qt, scroll, qtableview

Can anyone tell me why I can see the scrollbar from my `QTableView`, but can't use it? 
Anyone has an idea?

My code:

```
View::View()
{
}

void View::init()
{

    // add model and Table

    myModel= new Model();
    QTableView *myView=new QTableView( this );
    myView->setModel(myModel);
    QWidget *mywidget= new QWidget(this);

    // add buttons and labels

    QPushButton* btnaddtotable = new QPushButton( "Add to Table",this);
    btnaddtotable->setGeometry(50,20,100,40);
    QPushButton* btnFile = new QPushButton( "Open file",this);
    btnFile->setGeometry(50,20,100,40);
    QPushButton* btnOpenFile = new QPushButton( "Search file",this);
    btnFile->setGeometry(50,20,100,40);
    btnOpenFile->setGeometry(50,20,100,40);

    // connections

    QObject::connect ( btnaddtotable, SIGNAL ( clicked() ), this , SLOT(pushButtonClicked())) ;
    QObject::connect ( btnFile, SIGNAL ( clicked() ), this , SLOT(FileButtonClicked())) ;
    QObject::connect ( btnOpenFile, SIGNAL ( clicked() ), this , SLOT(OpenFileButtonClicked()));

    // named the buttons and labels

    myView->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("Table"));
    myView->setGeometry(QRect(20, 100, 361, 191));
    txtname = new QLineEdit(mywidget);
    txtname->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("txtname"));
    txtname->setGeometry(QRect(20, 30, 151, 31));
    txtvalue = new QLineEdit(mywidget);
    txtvalue->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("textEdit"));
    txtvalue->setGeometry(QRect(230, 30, 151, 31));
    label = new QLabel ("Name: ", mywidget );
    label->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("label"));
    label->setGeometry(QRect(20, 10, 61, 20));
    label_2 = new QLabel ("Value ", mywidget );
    label_2->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("label_2"));
    label_2->setGeometry(QRect(235, 10, 51, 20));
    QLabel *label3 = new QLabel ("DateiPfad: ", mywidget );
    label3->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("label"));
    label3->setGeometry(QRect(20, 305, 61, 20));
    txtPfad = new QLineEdit(mywidget);
    txtPfad->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("txtPfad"));
    txtPfad->setGeometry(QRect(80, 300, 300, 31));

    btnaddtotable->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushButton"));
    btnaddtotable->setGeometry(QRect(240, 70, 75, 23));
    btnFile->setGeometry(QRect(160, 70, 75, 23));
    btnOpenFile->setGeometry(QRect(80, 70, 75, 23));


    // searching the strings


    this->setGeometry(500,500,400,350);

    // for sorting
    sort_filter = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
    sort_filter->setSourceModel(myModel);
    // sort the first column
    sort_filter->sort(0);

    myView->setColumnWidth(0,179);
    myView->setColumnWidth(1,180);
    myView->setModel (sort_filter);
    // to check if exists
    sort_filter->setSourceModel(myModel);
    //myView->setCornerButtonEnabled(true);
    //myView->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    myView->setAutoScroll(true);
    myView->setAutoScrollMargin(20);
    myView->setHorizontalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerItem);

}
```

Have I forgotten anything?

Comment: This is indeed strange. I confirmed the issue. I'm trying to reduce the code to a minimum to show the issue, then it's easier to find the solution.

Comment: remove the autoscroll please and see if that works.

Comment: the Strange: i can add a scrollArea, but then i can't see the QTextEdits and Labels

Comment: no, when i remove the autoscroll . nothing is change ..

Comment: So this is very strange. I found out that if I remove everything except the table and a line edit, scrolling doesn't work. If I further remove the `setGeometry` for the line edit, scrolling works!

Comment: @thelittlePanda what's Model()?

Comment: Strange, if i remove the setGeometry, scrolling doesn't works :( i don't know .. you mean the line edit from my path ?

Comment: Well, I removed a lot ;) I uploaded my minimal example, you can compile and test yourself: http://ideone.com/M3fjJb

Comment: i have a model and a View, Model/view Programm. my view sends the model the date. Model put it in QLists and add it to my Table.

Comment: @thelittlePanda deW1 meant what type `Model` is exactly (how it is implemented). But according to my example, it doesn't really matter; I simply replaced it with a `QStandardItemModel` and we see the issue.

Comment: Oh, its a QAbstractTableModel

Comment: Okay, I found another hint. If you change the y-offset in `txtPfad->setGeometry(..., 300, ..., ...)` to something smaller or equal to 100 (where the table is), scrolling works. If it is larger than 100, scrolling doesn't work. My suspicion now is that the y-coordinate implicitly changes the tab order as well as the initial focus, which in turn makes scrolling work or not (whatever the exact reason is...).

Comment: Oh wait, it seems to be the x-coordinate which changes this behavior. I got very confused when playing around.

Comment: thank you, but its very Strange ;D

Answer (score 0):

You have a mess of widgets that overlap each other. I'd suggest using layouts so you wouldn't get problems like this.

But the main problem is your `QWidget *mywidget` object. You don't set a geometry to it, so it ends up covering your `QTableView`. If you set a stylesheet to it with a red background for example, you will see that happening.